# Understanding django Form initialisation

Tags: python, django, forms, init

I have a class like so:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=MultipleHiddenInput())
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.Textarea()

    def __init__(self, users, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.users.choices = users
        # self.fields['users'].choices = []
```

The commented line at the bottom works perfectly if I use it instead of `self.users`.

Am I right in thinking that `users`, `subject` and `message` are class level so that is why they are popped out of the attribute list?

So `self.fields` is the per object copy of the attributes in case I want to change them in some way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Form class uses the [`DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/forms/forms.py#L60), which enables the declarative syntax for the fields.

The implementation means that the form class and instance does not actually have an attribute `self.field_name` for each field. That is why trying to use `self.users` gives an error.

The fields of the form instance can be accessed as `self.fields`, which is created when you call `super` in the `__init__` method.

The fields of the form class can be accessed as `self.base_fields`.